# Can't find string in text file

Tags: python, string, file, python-2.7, search

Given a list of item numbers, I am trying to search through a text file with a list of recent item numbers, and identify any in this recent list. I then want to add any items that weren't already in the recent list.

My code is below, it just doesn't seem to be finding anything in the text file. Why isn't it working?

```
def filter_recent_items(items):
    recentitems = []
    with open('last 600 items.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for item in items:
            if item['ID'] in f:
                print 'In! --', item['ID']
            else:
                recentitems.append(item['ID'])
                print 'Out ---', item['ID']
        for item in recentitems:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)


items = [ {'ID': 1}, {'ID': 'test2'} ]     
filter_recent_items(items)
```

For example , my text file is:

```
test2

test1

1
```

but the above code returns

```
Out --- 1
Out --- test2
```

Comment: `if item['ID'] in f` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in how you're checking for the existence of the specified text. In your code `f` is a file object, used for reading and writing to/from a file. So when you check if

```
str in f
```

It's not checking what you think it is. (See below for details.)

Instead, you need to read in the lines of the file and then iterate through those lines and check for necessary string. Ex.

```
with open('last 600 items.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for l in lines:
        # check within each line for the presence of the items
```

In the above code exerpt, `f.readlines()` uses the file object to read the contents of the file and returns a list of strings, which are the lines within the file.

**EDITED** (credit to Peter Wood)

[Python Membership Details](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details)

In Python, when you use the syntax `x in y`, it checks for 2 things:

**Case 1:**  It first checks to see whether `y` has a `__contains__(b)` method. If so, it returns the result of `y.__contains__(x)`.

**Case 2:** If however, `y` does *not* have a `__contains__` method, but does define the `__iter__` method, Python instead uses *that* method to iterate over the contents of `y` and returns `True` if at any point one of the values being iterated over equals `x`. Otherwise, it returns `False`.

If we use your code as the example, at a certain point, it is checking the truth of the statement `"test2" in f`. Here `f` is an object of type `file`. ([Python File Object Description](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects)). File objects belong to Case 2 (i.e. they *don't* have `__contains__`, they *do* have `__iter__`.

So the code will go through each line and see whether your input strings are **equal** to any of the lines in the file. And since each line ends with the char `\n`, your strings are never going to return `True`.

To elaborate, while `"test2" in "test2\n"` would return `True`, the test that's actually being performed here is: `"test2" == "test2\n"`, which is `False`.

You can test how this works on your file by hand. For exmaple, if we want to see if `"test2" in f` should return `True`:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    x = iter(f)
    while(True):
        try:
            line = x.next()
        except:
            break
        print(line)
        print(line == "test2")
```

You'll notice that it prints out each line (including the newline at the end) and that the result of `line == "test2"` is always `False`.

If however we were to try: `"test2\n" in f`, the result would be `True`.

**End Edit**

Comment: `'test2\n' in f` is `True`

Comment: See [membership test details](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details). `in` will use `iter` as `file` doesn't define `__contains__`, but does define `__iter__`. It will iterate until it's all used up or until it finds a match. `iter` will return one line from the file, so `'test2\n'` will match, whereas `'test2'` won't.

Comment: Just to be clear, it has to be an exact match. From the link: *`x in y` is true if some value `z` with `x == z` is produced while iterating over `y`*

Comment: oh that's interesting I didn't realize that. I was just about to ask why it wouldn't return a partial match when `"test2" in "test2\n"` returns `True`, but you just answered it. Thanks, I'll add an edit to my post.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, `if "somestring" in f` will always fail. `f` is a file object which, when you iterate over it, produces lines of text. One or more of those LINES might contain your text, so instead you could do:

```
if any("targetstring" in line for line in f):
    # success
```

This is memory-saving versus the `f.read()` or `f.readlines()` approaches, which both stream the whole file into memory before doing anything.

@PeterWood points out in the comments that some of your target strings aren't actually strings. You should see to that, too. `all(isinstance(item["ID"], str) for item in items)` should be `True`.

Comment: Also, the first `item['ID']` is an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Print out your data store, **f**.  First of all, I expect that you have embedded newline characters that prevent the items from matching: "1" doesn't match "1\n".  Second, note that **with open" gives you a generator, not a list or tuple.  You can't scan the list multiple times.  You don't have the data from it until you iterate through it somehow.

You need code to get all the elements into memory, such as

```
content = f.read().split("\n")
for item in items:
    if item["ID" in content:
```

Comment: Also, is a list of dictionaries really what you want for input?  I would think that a simple list would do, such as **[1, "item2"]**.